# Convert a selector to its class_addMethod() encoding at compile time

Tags: objective-c, encode

I have the following Objective-C code in a testing harness for some crazy low-level code (don't ask):

```
/* This category is declared here but not defined anywhere.
 * It lets me write
 *   id MyNewClass = objc_lookUpClass("MyNewClass");
 *   [MyNewClass class_method];
 * without spurious compiler warnings.
 */
@interface NSObject (MyNewClass)
+(void) class_method;
+(void) class_method_taking_int: (int) f;
-(int) method_returning_int: (int) i;
@end

...
{
    Class MyNewClass = objc_allocateClassPair([NSObject class], "MyNewClass", 0);
    Class MyNewClass_meta = object_getClass(cls);
    class_addMethod(MyNewClass_meta, @selector(class_method),
        (IMP)..., "v@:");
    class_addMethod(MyNewClass_meta, @selector(class_method_taking_int:),
        (IMP)..., "v@:i");
    class_addMethod(MyNewClass, @selector(method_returning_int:),
        (IMP)..., "i@:i");
    objc_registerClassPair(MyNewClass);
}
```

I'd like to be able to eliminate all those literal `"v@:i"` and so on. After all, those are supposed to be just the encodings of the method signatures as listed in the `NSObject (MyNewClass)` category. So I feel like I ought to be able to write something like

```
    class_addMethod(MyNewClass_meta, @selector(class_method_taking_int:),
        (IMP)..., @encode(__typeof__(+[NSObject class_method_taking_int:])));
```

Of course the syntax above is fantasy, but shouldn't there be *something* like this in Objective-C? And then I could hide the whole thing behind a simple macro and the code would be just beautiful.

Notice that I *cannot* use `methodSignatureForSelector`, because that assumes that I have an object that responds to the given selector, which I don't, because I haven't registered my class yet.

Also notice that the format of the string expected by `class_addMethod` isn't the same as the format of the string returned by `@encode(foo)`, and in fact `@encode(foo)` can't encode function types at all — it just gives back `"?"` or `"^?"`. So I guess I can't literally use `@encode`.

But is there anything I *can* do?

Comment: without having researched your question with the detail it deserves... just offhand, could you not _query the selector_ via `NSSelectorFromString(@"unregisteredSelector")` to wrestle the method signature asunder... even before "registering it".

Comment: @alexgray I don't see what you mean, sorry. (Consider posting a longer answer, which you can always delete later if you want? :))  `NSSelectorFromString(@"unregisteredSelector")` is AFAIK exactly equivalent to `@selector(unregisteredSelector)`; and it still doesn't tell me the *signature* of that method. (Recall that **selectors** aren't the same thing as **methods**.) But it's also worth noting that *I personally* haven't worked with Objective-C for about six months; of course other SO readers might like to see the question answered, but I'm not personally invested in the question anymore.